# what is a general algorithm to find a nonempty integer subset that have integers add up to 0?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

what is a general algorithm to compute if a set have nonempty integer subset that have integers add up to 0?

i would like to know one with the least tries and the proof of it.

Example:{−2, −3, 15, 14, 7, −10} have integers added up to zeros since {−2, −3, −10, 15} add up to zero

i would also like to know the level of it - undergraduate or graduate?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem - this problem is believed to be 'hard' (it's NP-complete), and many algorithms are known for it.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - i can't read the computer langauage, may someone put those algorithm in english and math langauage?

Comment: @Victor: What "computer language" are you talking about? The only remotely computerlike notation in the Wikipedia article is a block of high-level _pseudocode_. If you cannot read _that_, you shouldn't be trying to understand algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the well known *subset sum* problem, and there is an $O\left ((\sum x_i) ^2\right )$ *dynamic programming* (based on a recurrence relation) algorithm. Wikipedia has a nice explanation of it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution

What do you mean when you ask for the algorithm with the "least tries"? If you mean runtime, this algorithm is the fastest.

Regarding the level, a student in an introductory computer science course should be able to devise a solution of this kind.